# ASP.NET MVC Ajax expandable form using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My knowledge of jquery isn't very vast but what I'm trying to do is allow a user to click a button on a form to add more fields to the form to be submitted to the form itself... Something similar to how gmail used to handle email attachments by adding a bunch of input fields for each file, anyone have some pointers on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a button with id="buttonId" and a div where you want to put your new fields into with id="contentDiv":

```
$('#buttonId').click(
   function() {
      $('<div>someinput, like textboxes ecc</div>')
         .appendTo($('#contentDiv'));
   }
);
```

With this syntax you can operate on the new content directly, like:

```
$('#buttonId').click(
   function() {
      $('<div>someinput, like textboxes ecc</div>')
         .hide()
         .appendTo($('#contentDiv'))
         .fadeIn('fast');
   }
);
```

So the new content is faded in instead of just showed.

Comment: I forgot about appendTo,  this looks much cleaner :)

Comment: for some reason this isn't working on my page... syntax is the same, nothing happening on the page, everything being pulled in correctly not sure why it's having problems

Comment: Be sure to match all the IDs of the example (write it without sharp "#" in the tag, but be sure to put the "#" in the selector). Then, mMake sure you provide correct HTML content in the selector.

Answer (score 3):

Without writing all of the code for you, create a container, like a div inside your form.

```
<div id="morefields"></div>
```

Keep a global var with the # of fields

```
var fieldCount = 0;
```

Then add to the html of that div

```
fieldCount++;
var id = 'fieldname' + fieldCount;
var fields = $("#morefields").html() + "<input id='" + id + "' name = '" + id + "' />";
$("#morefields").html( fields);
```

have your controller function accept FormCollection as a parameter, read the fields.

There hopefully is a cleaner way which someone will post.  This is how I've done it before.  Code may not compile, written from memory, but you get the gist.

Comment: The appendTo below looks cleaner.

Comment: (+1) maybe I would just name the inputs like this: name='fieldname['+fieldCount']'; so ModelBinding can be used in controllers action.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery,

**Static Form Data**

You can .show() and .hide() a DIV on a button click.  This will let you toggle the displaying of your extra info DIV.

[link](http://docs.jquery.com/Show)

or

**Dynamic Form Data**
Using .load(), you can dynamically load content from a file/the server and use .html() to add it into your form.

[link](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

Write back with which one you want to do and I'll provide more info if you want.

Comment: dynamic, because i wont know how many items a user will want to add

Answer (score 0):

There's a plug-in for that :). See [jquery-dynamic-form](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-dynamic-form/).